# Should one practice celibacy even after self-realization?

Tags: moksha, celibacy

To be self-realized one must practice celibacy.

Should one practice celibacy even *after* achieving self-realization?

Comment: Self realized person bliss like that trillioner wealth and sexual desire is like offering 1 rs. Can it satisfy him who owns trillion

Comment: @PrasannaR Don't know about that. Scrooge McDuck really seems into his [number one dime](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Number_One_Dime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to be sexually active after self realization. The reason is that the semen becomes like sugar crystals.

> MAHIMA: "Sir, why does a man become deluded by worldly objects?"
>
> MASTER: "It is because he lives in their midst without having realized
> God. Man never succumbs to delusion after he has realized God. The
> moth no longer enjoys darkness if it has once seen the light.
>
> "To be able to realize God, one must practise absolute continence.
> Sages like Sukadeva are examples of an urdhareta. (A man of unbroken
> and complete continence.) Their chastity was absolutely unbroken.
> There is another class, who previously have had discharges of semen
> but who later on have controlled them. A man controlling the seminal
> fluid for twelve years develops a special power. He grows a new inner
> nerve called the nerve of memory. Through that nerve he remembers all,
> he understands all.
>
> "Loss of semen impairs the strength. But it does not injure one if one
> loses it in a dream. That semen one gets from food. What remains after
> nocturnal discharge is enough. But one must not know a woman.
>
> "The semen that remains after nocturnal discharge is very 'refined'.
> The Lahas kept jars of molasses in their house. Every jar had a hole
> in it. **After a year they found that the molasses had crystallized like
> sugar candy.** The unnecessary watery part had leaked out through the
> hole.
>
> "A sannyasi must absolutely renounce woman. You are already involved;
> but that doesn't matter.
>
> "A sannyasi must not look even at the picture of a woman. But this is
> too difficult for an ordinary man. Sa, re, ga, ma, pa, dha, ni are the
> seven notes of the scale. It is not possible to keep your voice on
> 'ni' a long time.
>
> "To lose semen is extremely harmful for a sannyasi. Therefore he must
> live so carefully that he will not have to see the form of a woman. He
> must keep himself away from a woman even if she is a devotee of God.
> It is injurious for him to look even at the picture of a woman. He
> will lose semen in a dream, if not in the waking state.
>
> "A sannyasi may have control over his senses, but to set an example to
> mankind he should not talk with women. He must not talk to one very
> long, even if she is a devotee of God.
>
> "Living as a sannyasi is like observing the ekadasi without drinking
> even a drop of water. There are two other ways of observing the day.
> You may eat fruit or take luchi and curry. With the luchi and curry
> you may also take slices of bread soaked in milk. (All laugh.)

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 20, Rules for Householders and Monks, March 23, 1884**

Comment: Why does the seman become "semen becomes like sugar crystals". And even if it is crystallized the body can produce new semen.

Comment: @DarkKnight, the Guru when initiating transfers spiritual power to the disciple. If the disciple continues to do spiritual practice as suggested by the Guru for a long time then this power changes the nature of the semen. This power also ensures that the semen remains like sugar crystals. Hinduism has a scripture part and a spiritual practice part. The spiritual part of Hinduism is not publicly discussed.

Comment: OK thanks for clarification

Comment: but what about woman she doesn't need seman.

Comment: The key question is why? why would a realized sanyasin want to have intercourse with a woman? Generally, people do so, because they experience short term pleasure. But, if you have permanent, constant happiness that is much higher than the short term pleasure as would be the case with a realized being, and if you are logical, you wouldn't want to trade the two levels of happiness.

Comment: @DarkKnight, the spiritual power will in the long run kill the desire to have sexual relations with another person for a self realized person. The self realized person whether a man or a woman would not want to have sex.

Comment: @lamThat because maharishi's have wife's

Comment: Even Greek philosophers, who did not get any such experience and based their arguments solely on reason, avoided sexual activity and led a life of austerity. Both men and women. Examples of Men philosophers - Marcus Aurelius, Socrates, etc. Woman Philosopher - Hypatia.

Comment: Can't women become self realized? Why is this all written for men?

Comment: Yes women can also become self realized. Unfortunately I have not come across any source that describes what happens to a self realized woman.

Comment: @DarkKnight, Okay I see what you were trying to ask. But having intercourse for progeny is rational and practical. For a brahmana, I think rules were laid out on the frequency of having intercourse, it was about once a year. Brahmanas who followed these guidelines, were well respected. Example, Sri Ramakrishna's parents were such brahmanas as is mentioned in the gospel of sri ramakrishna

Comment: @lamThat  "I see what you were trying to ask" . What do you mean by this. "But having intercourse for progeny is rational and practical" but intercourse is intercourse, in both you will feel pressure.

Comment: I meant that you were asking for intercourse in general and not about intercourse for fun. That would explain my first comment on this answer. I presumed the will to procreate in your question, was same as those for ordinary men, desire not rationality.

Comment: Yes, that is true. The physical effects will be the same in one particular instant. But, that is why I said, for grihastas/married people, it is the frequency that matters, as you have to have intercourse for progeny anyway. If the frequency is very low, it will cause minimal damage to the body and mind. But, if it is too much, it will increase trishna, the thirst/longing for desires and also damage the mind.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary. King Janaka told Sage Suka that he can get married and have children and till can remain unattached and self realised.

Well it's a huge discussion, of which i am just giving a part. You can read it in [Srimad Devi Bhagavatam Mahā Puranam](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57117.html) in Book I Chapter 15-19.

**Srimad Devi Bhagwatam Mahā Puranam 1:18.:**

> *28-35. Janaka said :-- O Lord of Brāhmins! what you have said is, in my opinion, all quite true; nothing is false. Still hear. Know what my most worshipful Guru Deva has spoken to me is, in fact, true (and nothing else). You are now intending to quit the company of your father and go to the forest; well and good! but even then you will undoubtedly have the company of deer, etc.; see, also, that when the five elements, earth, water, air, etc., are present, encompassing everywhere, how, then, can you expect to be free from all companions? So, O Muni! when you will have to think always of your food, how, then, can you be said to be free from all cares? Again, even if you go to the forest, you will have to think there also for your staff, deer skin, etc.; so you can take my case, too, of thinking of my kingdom, whether I think or not, as your thinking of staff, deer skin, etc., your heart is tainted with Vikalpa Jñān (knowledge of doubt, duality, etc.); and therefore you have come here from a far-off country. But my heart is free from any such doubt and I am remaining quite cheerful here. O best of Brāhmins! I have got no doubt whatsoever on any point, and therefore I take my food and go to sleep with great pleasure. “I am not bound up by this world” this idea gives me constant happiness of the highest degree. But you consider that you are bound and therefore you feel always constant pain. So leave off your idea that you are bound, and be happy. “This body is mine” this knowledge leads to my bondage; and “This body is not mine” this knowledge leads to freedom so know this verily that all this wealth, kingdom, etc., are not mine.*
>
> *36-45. Sūta said :-- Hearing these words of the royal sage, Śūka Deva became exceedingly glad and pronounced “Sadhu” “Sādhu” (true saint, indeed a true saint, well said) and went away without any delay to the pleasant Āśrama of Vyāsa. Vyāsa, too, seeing his son come back, became very glad and embraced him and took the smell of his head and asked about his welfare again and again. Then Śūka Deva, well conversant with the Śāstras and ever ready in studying the Vedas, sat by the side of his father, with an enlightened mind, in his lovely Āśrama and thinking of the state of the highsouled Janaka in his kingdom, began to feel the highest peace. Though Śūka adopted the path of Yoga, yet he married the daughter of a Muni, named Pivarī, very beautiful, fortunate, enhancing the glory of her father’s family...."*

I hope this clarifies your queries.